# Multiprocessing in Python, variable assignment

Tags: python, variables, multiprocessing

I am having this issue in Python.
Consider these two code snippets:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

vart = None

def func(i): print(vart)

def print_fun():
    pool = Pool(2)
    pool.map(func, range(2))        
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    pool.terminate()
    #vart = 'init'

print_fun()
vart = 'init'
print_fun()
```

As you would expect, this code prints:

```
None
None
init
init
```

However, if I slightly modify the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

vart = None

def func(i): print(vart)

def print_fun():
    pool = Pool(2)
    pool.map(func, range(2))         
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    pool.terminate()
    vart = 'init'

print_fun()
#vart = 'init'
print_fun()
```

This doesn't print the expected result anymore, but rather:

```
None
None
None
None
```

What's happening here? Why is the "print_fun" function not updating the global variable, since the instruction is called after closing the Pool?

Comment: Why is `vart = 'init'` commented out?

Comment: To highlight the difference between the two snippets.
In the second one, vart = 'init' is executed inside print_fun()

Comment: vart is local in the second case. you need to add `global vart` in your function

Comment: Uh yeah, today I am too tired I guess... I get it now!
Thank you!!